# How to resolve NoReverseMatch Exception for 'app_list' with upload files in changelist view page of model admin using django 3?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Code snippets that I was able to add so far:
Model class:

```
class MboxForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MboxForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        csv_file = forms.FileField(required=True,
                                  label="Select CSV file")

    class Meta:
        model = Mbox
        fields = ['some_field',
        ]
        
        widgets = {
                   'csv_file': forms.FileInput(),
        }
```

In admin.py:

```
class MboxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [import_from_csv,
               export_to_csv]
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['form'] = MboxForm

        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path("upload_csv",
                 self.upload_csv, name='upload_csv')
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
    
    urls = property(get_urls)

    def upload_csv(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MboxForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('admin/change_list.html')
            else :
                return render(request, 'admin/change_list.html',
                              {'form': form,
                              'opts': Mbox._meta})
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                'admin/change_list.html',
                context
            )

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = {}
        extra_context['submit_csv_form'] = MboxForm
    
        if 'action' in request.POST and request.POST['action'] == 'import_from_csv':
            if not request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME):
                post = request.POST.copy()
                for u in Mbox.objects.all():
                    post.update({admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME: str(u.id)})
                request._set_post(post)

        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

This button displays in place of the add button in the listing page with the template with the file browser to upload any file.

{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list %}

{% block object-tools %}
{% if has_add_permission %}

```
        {% block object-tools-items %}

        <form id="upload-csv-form" method="POST"
      action="{% url 'admin:upload_csv'  %}"
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}

          <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
      {% comment %}       
          <p>{{ submit_csv_form.as_p }}</p>
      {% endcomment %}        
          <p>{{ submit_csv_form.csv_file.errors }}</p>

          <p><input type="file" value="CSV file" />
          <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            <!-- input type="reset" value="Reset"> -->
        </form>
        {% endblock %}

      </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The error That I get on clicking the upload button:
NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

> Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not
> found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|mailmanager)/$'

mailmanager is the app for which the model: Mbox exists. Besides where do I place this change_view.html template in  the template structure for only this model. I tried placing the template under myproject/templates/admin/templates/mailmanager/mbox, but it is not found. Also I don't wish to replace the 'Add model' button but have this placed next to it in the default model change list template.

I have followed the stack link so far but not got it working as yet. :[Upload CSV file in django admin list view, replacing add object button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641756/upload-csv-file-in-django-admin-list-view-replacing-add-object-button) Please guide .